# Line height for a specific font

Tags: css, font-face, vertical-alignment, unicode-range

In css I have defined a custom font for a specific rage of characters:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Sahel;
    src: url(../font/Sahel-FD.ttf);
    unicode-range: U+0600-06FF;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Sahel;
    src: url(../font/Sahel-FD-Bold.ttf);
    unicode-range: U+0600-06FF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I want to change `line-height` only for this font, but adding this property in a `@font-face` rule has no effect.

How can I do that?

Comment: You need to change it where you apply the font family

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have not applied it anywhere explicitly but in the rule itself with `unicode-range` property.

Comment: I know, and as you can see here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face there is no way to define a default line-height

Comment: @Mahozad What is the effect you are trying to achieve? Maybe y0ou can do something with vertical-align.

Comment: @MrLister When a user changes the site language (therefor the above font will be applied) the height of the buttons are increased (it's because of the font). If I set `line-height` globally, then it affects the default language as well.